# Как в Eclipse собрать пример HelloJNI из Android NDK?

Tags: eclipse, android, android-ndk

Как в Eclipse собрать пример HelloJNI из Android NDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить дополнительный сборщик.

```
Project -> Properties -> Builders -> New
Location -> /path-to/android-ndk/ndk-build
Working Directory -> Browse Workspace -> HelloJni
```